Distance between objects with array modifier
I'd like to make the following structure below using a non-destructive workflow (array and mirror modifiers). Is that possible? The way I was able to build as seen was by applying the array modifier, which I'd prefer not to do.

When I try this without applying the array modifier, this is the result I get (which doesn't have the correct spacing):


What did you do after applying the array? Manually modify the mesh? If not, then maybe check the 'merging' option on the array so they become a connected, single mesh

Yeah after applying the array on the first one I manually modified the mesh. I want to keep the array but I want the distance between the stripes to shrink as I scale down the vertices.

It's hard to tell from the picture how you are twisting the object but if it was a flat object at first, you could make it follow a curve to bend it on itself. In edit mode, you can change the radius of a curve control point in the N menu. This distorts the object that is following the curve in the same manner that you have in the pic. You could maybe use a latize modifier instead but it's hard to tell from the picture how you are bending it

Check out the method I describe in my answer to this question. This is what I like to do when i need to "apply" the modifiers to work on the object further without actually applying them.

Thank you both! I don't think there's a work-around yet re: applying the modifiers for my specific use case but I appreciate the help :)
